# Calculation of removing a nucleon from a nucleus

Tags: particle-physics

I would like to calculate the energy needed to remove one nucleon - proton or neutron - from a nucleus. What is the equation to be used?

Comment: You might be interested in the binding energy for a nucleon. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy

Comment: @RadhaKrishna It will be useful to you, after reading what Sandesh recommended, to read also the [question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160366/binding-energies-of-be/160373#160373) and the answers.

Comment: I would look at the Saxon-Woods potential http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woods%E2%80%93Saxon_potential and more generally the shell nuclear model