# Beryllium(8) Never exists!

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy

Why does  Be(8) never exist and decay into 2 alpha particles? 
Here, given Binding energy of Be(8)=7.064MeV & Binding energy of He(4)=7.08MeV.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding energies of Be](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160366/)

Comment: You need to compare the energy levels of $^{8}$Be vs two $\alpha$ particles. You will find (http://www.tunl.duke.edu/nucldata/figures/08figs/menu08.shtml) that the two $\alpha$ particles lie 91.8keV below the bound $^{8}$Be ground state.